# How to check if a Linked-List is empty in python?

Tags: python, linked-list

I created a linked list that i want to check if it is empty, and if it is empty, it will return `True`, and if it is not empty, it will return `False`. I've tried a couple solutions for this. but this is one of the solutions i tried.

```
def isEmpty(self):
    current_node = self.head
    return current_node == None
```

But it seems to return False even when it is empty. BUt here is the whole code from the list so you can see how ive set it up

```
class Node:

    def __init__(self, data = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = Node()

    def display(self):
        elements = []

        current_node = self.head
        while current_node.next != None:
            current_node = current_node.next
            elements.append(current_node.data)
        return elements

    def add(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        current_node = self.head
        while current_node.next != None:
            current_node = current_node.next
        current_node.next = new_node

    def isEmpty(self):
        current_node = self.head
        return current_node == None
```

How would i fix this problem?

Comment: self.head is always a new (empty) node object? And current node will always be set to this empty node object? Am I reading this right?

Comment: @Wimanicesir Yes, you are reading this correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def isEmpty(self):
    return self.head.next is None
```

Comment: Use `is` to compare against `None`, and this can be a single line: `return self.head.next is None`

Comment: Why `return True if (condition) else False`, as opposed to `return (condition)` ?

Comment: `return True if (condition) else False` works like that: `if (condition): return True  else: return False`

Comment: Yes, but it is redundant as `(condition)` is already evaluated as `True` or `False`, you can simply return it djrectly